# How to install Visual Studio 2015 to use an existing installation of NodeJs, Cordova and android SDK

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm currenlty using **nodejs**, **cordova**, **android sdk**.
I'm trying to install **visual studio 2015** but it seems to want to download and install these packages again, creating its own copy.

I want to use the existing tools.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point Visual Studio to use your settings by following steps below:

1. On the Visual Studio menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, choose Tools for Apache Cordova, and then choose Environment Variable Overrides.

More details in the [Configure the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx#env_var)  on MSDN.

When specify values other then defaults take following notes in consideration:

1. Visual Studio sometimes, has problems with node 0.12, it requires 0.10
2. It may have problems with cordova 5.0.0, better use 4.3.0

Comment: I believe this is a correct answer, but visual studio sometimes, has problems with node 0.12, it requires 0.10, and it may have problems.with cordova 5.0.0, better use 4.3.0

Comment: Thanks, add to the answer your notes.